# conversion operator template: safety and usability

Tags: c++, templates, boost, operator-overloading

I'm writing a C++ [opensource project for configuration loading](https://github.com/alessandro-pezzato/swiftree) (from tree data structures like xml and json) based on `boost::ptree` and `boost::lexical_cast`.

To allow implicit conversion from a `Tree` structure to any primitive or user defined types, I've
added a conversion operator template:

```
template<class Type>
operator Type() const {
    return boost::lexical_cast<Type>(this->toString());
}
```

**[full code here](https://github.com/alessandro-pezzato/swiftree/blob/master/src/Tree.h#L94-97)**

This works with types handled by boost::ptree. For all other types, the user can
specialize this template:

```
namespace swiftree {
template<>
Tree::operator Vector3() const {
    Vector3 ret;
    ret.x = value<float>("x");
    ret.y = value<float>("y");
    ret.z = value<float>("z");
    return ret;
}
}
```

So the user con do this:

```
Vector3 position = tree["position"];
```

**Are there any drawbacks to using such technique? Are there better alternative ways to achieve the same?**

Comment: Boost ptree already has a similar feature. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745716/change-how-boostproperty-tree-reads-translates-strings-to-bool You can add translators to all types you need

Comment: The idea behind this project is to have a more concise way to get data than ptree has. `translator_between` seems to be an alternative to the operator template... but why it's better?

Comment: This might depend on needs and opinion. I intentionally created only a comment, since I don't want to say it's better or worse. I'm fine with using a standard `ptree`, depending on your needs your `operator` approach might be better

Comment: The opinion of many in the C++ community has gradually become "implicit conversions are evil". They frequently create a mess with overload resolution and generic code