# How do I extend boost property_tree to handle custom types?

Tags: boost-propertytree

Boost PropertyTree allows serialization of custom types by providing a specialization of `translator_between`, but I couldn't find any documentation, and the code can be quite cryptic.

Comment: There is [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745716/change-how-boostproperty-tree-reads-translates-strings-to-bool)  regarding this, but the answer only provides one example, not a general description.

Answer (score 3):

The general pattern for a custom type `CustomType` is:

```
namespace boost {
namespace property_tree {

template<>
struct translator_between<KeyType, CustomType>
{
  struct type {
    typedef KeyType internal_type;
    typedef CustomType external_type;
    boost::optional<external_type> get_value(const internal_type& str);
    boost::optional<internal_type> put_value(const external_type& obj);
  };
};

} // namespace property_tree
} // namespace boost
```

`KeyType` must be `std::string` for `ptree` and `iptree`, and in general must be identical to the first template argument of your `basic_ptree`. You could make `type` a template if you're into that sort of thing.

The two typedefs `internal_type` and `external_type` are mandatory, they are used in `detail::is_translator<Translator>` in `ptree_utils.hpp`.

Note that you could make `translator_between::type` a typedef, but you don't technically need to. I suspect they do it in all the examples to make the definition marginally prettier.

The arguments of `get_value` and `put_value` don't necessarily need to be `const &`, but I can't think of a reason to change that.

Beware in general of where you put your declarations of `translator_between`, especially if the streaming operators are overloaded for your CustomType. In this case you should probably put the `translator_between` next to the declarations of the operators.